# multiprocessing in Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am using LogisticRegression algorithm

it works fine, except it is taking long time to finish

I decided to use multiprocessing feature (n_jobs=-1) as per https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

but no change in the performance

Here is my code

```
mdl = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
mdl.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=mdl.predict(X_test)
```

How can I use it on LogisticRegression?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to solve a binary classification problem, in which case there would be no benefit.

Comment: indeed it is binary classification, but why there is no benefit?

Comment: The design of the function is that each class can train on a single core, so since you don't have multiple classes there is no work to distribute.  Binary classification is limited to a single core.

Comment: How to distribute multi-label multi-classification model over multiple processors?

Comment: Your current set up is fine if you simply pass a multi-class training set.  The default behavior as per the documentation is to autodetect binary/multi class, and since you have already passed the n_jobs=-1 it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing multiclass classification?
If your data does not have more than two classes, setting the `n_jobs` argument is virtually useless.

To improve speed try feature engineering to reduce the number of features.

You could also try changing the solver. Here's what the documentation says:
*"For small datasets, ‘liblinear’ (used to be the
default) is a good choice, whereas ‘sag’ and
‘saga’ are faster for large ones.
For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’,
‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘lbfgs’ handle multinomial
loss; ‘liblinear’ is limited to one-versus-rest
schemes."*

There are also some parameters like `tol` you could try changing.

Finally, if nothing works, use another model.

Comment: is there any alternative to scikit-learn's LogisticRegression which utilizes multiprocessing?

Comment: Yeah, lots of them. All the ensemble and decision tree methods support multiprocessing (ExtraTrees, Voting classifiers, random forests etc). You can check the documentation for more algorithms

Comment: I think I must clarify. I meant an implementation of Logistic Regression that utilized multiple CPU cores. Is there any?